# It gives me ImportError when I import `from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor`. Does anyone know why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I get ImportError when I try to import:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "queue.py", line 4, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    from .thread import ThreadPoolExecutor as te
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 11, in <module>
    import queue
  File "/Users/tigranfahradyan/Desktop/python3/learning/queue.py", line 4, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    from .thread import ThreadPoolExecutor as te
ImportError: cannot import name 'ThreadPoolExecutor' from 'concurrent.futures.thread' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py)
```

It seems that something is wrong with `queue` module.
Can anyone help to figure this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a case of dependency confusion there. Check the stack-trace. See that line where it's trying to import `queue` and that resolves to `/Users/.../queue.py`. I'm guessing that's some file you wrote. The python import mechanism is confused between that `queue.py` and the `queue.py` of `concurrent.futures`.

Try renaming your `queue.py` file to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your Queue file. It should work if we import **from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor** in python 3.2 or later version. It would be very happy to look into it if you could share snippet of queue.py file to investigate more. Try changing queue.py name and run, if not works, share your snippet, i will look into into for you.